# How would I model a Gson object that can handle a dynamic field?

Tags: java, json, gson

An API my application is communicating with sends responses that look like:

```
{
    Code: 200,
    Message: "HELLO",
    Data: []
}
```

The Data field is always an array of *SOMETHING*.  But that *something* could be a single node of text, another array of something else, or any other of an assortment of different objects.

In the below example, the data node is an *array of an array of car objects*.

```
Data: [ [ {car:1}, {car:2} ] ]
```

Another return type could be an array of insect objects:

```
Data: [ {insect : spider} ]
```

I would like to design a Gson object to handle this and was wondering what the best way would be.

My first thought is to have an abstract class that holds the `Code` and `Message` fields, and then have many sub-types that all have their own `Data` field.  Then I would just call `.fromJson()` passing it the sub-class.

Is there a more optimal way to design it so that Gson would handle the differences?

Comment: Why do you deleted this? got the solution? http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:jFfdaPx73k0J:stackoverflow.com/questions/18064009/how-do-i-extend-gsonrequest-so-that-it-can-use-a-generic-type-for-deserializatio+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in&client=ubuntu

Comment: @LOG_TAG Yeah I just passed the TypeToken to the constructor of the request object and then inside parseNetworkResponse I passed the token to gson.fromJson and casted the result to T:  (T)gson.fromJson(json, token)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what I believe is the best answer.  Fairly straightforward!

Make the class generic and supply the type by creating a TypeToken before passing to Gson:

```
   public class Response<T> {

        private String code;
        private String message;
        private List<T> data;
    }
```

Then when using Gson:

```
   Type myCarListResponse = new TypeToken<Response<List<Car>>>(){}.getType();
   Response<List<Car>> response = gson.fromJson(json, myCarListResponse);
```

Replace > with the type you are expecting from the `Data` node.  The above example satisfies the first example from the original post.

To satisfy the second example:

```
  Type myInsectResponse = new TypeToken<Response<Insect>>(){}.getType();
  Response<Insect> response = gson.fromJson(json, myInsectResponse);
```

Comment: Elegant solution. I suppose to post this.

Comment: How can we change  gson.fromJson(json, clazz) inside https://gist.github.com/ficusk/5474673  any help? it should return list as a response!

Answer (score 0):

In Jackson, you can use `@JsonAnyGetter/Setter` to achieve this.

Refer http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_458.html, http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureAnyGetter